# Recomended Web Api Client

Tags: asp.net

I've developed a Asp.Net Web Api using OWin to authenticate and authorizing users. Now my Client (customer), wants a web app client to connect with de API, but:

- Javascript (angular, knockoutjs or jquery) + HTML5 is out the question beacuse my customer does not want to expose the code even if non business logic is in it.
- The alternative I've came up, is to develop an mvc or webforms webapp which in serversides connect to the web api. I'm not sure if this alternative is recommended.
- What other choices should I contemplate?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Some code will be exposed to the client anyway. What kind of code client doesn't what to expose - and what you mean by "exposed"?

Comment: @Fabio Thanks for comment, By exposed I mean downloadable code and by code any piece of code.

Comment: With almost any approach you will need to download some code. In web application it will be javascript, with desktop  application you need to download/install .dll libraries, One approach what can be considered - using applications installed on the "secure" server through Remote connection, but in this case user will have access to the .dll of application too.